# Solving the equation $10^{-x} = 5^{2x}$ with logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$10^{-x} = 5^{2x}$$

I'm having trouble isolating $x$. I get both logs on one side and then I'm stuck because I have nothing to divide with on the other side, and I can't factor it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered what the graphs of these functions look like? Visually, it's clear that $x=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $10^{-x} = 5^{2x}$, then $-x\log(10) = 2x\log(5)$ thus either $x=0$ or $-\log(10)=2\log(5)$ (or both). Since $-\log(10)\neq2\log(5)$ we must conclude that $x=0$.

Comment: Bravo! Thank you so much for the quick response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help.

Comment: Once we get 0, how could be both as you say. If the two things were equal, would we then conclude that it itself is a solution?

Comment: If we would have $-\log(10)=2\log(5)$, any $x$ would be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If $-x\log 10 = 2x\log 5$ then $(2x\log5) + (x\log10)=0$, so $x\cdot(2\log5 -\log10)=0$.

So it reduces to $x$ times some constant equals $0$.  And then the only thing you need to know about that constant is that it's not $0$.